# In Delphi can a string be converted to a set

Tags: string, delphi, set

For instance

```
Font.Style = StringToSet('[fsBold, fsUnderline]');
```

of course there would need to be some typeinfo stuff in there, but you get the idea.  I'm using Delphi 2007.

Comment: @Ken White: Questions without good enough answers means the answers are still not good enough.

Comment: @ian it's far more common for the questions to be poor than it is for the answers to be poor

Answer (score 13, accepted):

check this code, is not exactly the same syntax which you propose , but works setting the value of a set from a string.

```
uses
 TypInfo;

procedure StringToSet(Const Values,AProperty:string;Instance: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(GetPropInfo(Instance.ClassInfo, AProperty)) then
     SetSetProp(Instance,AProperty,Values);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringToSet('[fsBold, fsUnderline, fsStrikeOut]','Style',Label1.Font);
end;
```

Comment: Your variant is tied to published properties (GetPropInfo call), and thus stringly-typed.

Answer (score 11):

Also see my old post: [SetToString, StringToSet](http://tondrej.blogspot.com/2007/10/settostring-stringtoset.html) for a solution (Delphi 2007, IIRC) without a need for published property RTTI:

```
uses
  SysUtils, TypInfo;

function GetOrdValue(Info: PTypeInfo; const SetParam): Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;

  case GetTypeData(Info)^.OrdType of
    otSByte, otUByte:
      Result := Byte(SetParam);
    otSWord, otUWord:
      Result := Word(SetParam);
    otSLong, otULong:
      Result := Integer(SetParam);
  end;
end;

procedure SetOrdValue(Info: PTypeInfo; var SetParam; Value: Integer);
begin
  case GetTypeData(Info)^.OrdType of
    otSByte, otUByte:
      Byte(SetParam) := Value;
    otSWord, otUWord:
      Word(SetParam) := Value;
    otSLong, otULong:
      Integer(SetParam) := Value;
  end;
end;

function SetToString(Info: PTypeInfo; const SetParam; Brackets: Boolean): AnsiString;
var
  S: TIntegerSet;
  TypeInfo: PTypeInfo;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';

  Integer(S) := GetOrdValue(Info, SetParam);
  TypeInfo := GetTypeData(Info)^.CompType^;
  for I := 0 to SizeOf(Integer) * 8 - 1 do
    if I in S then
    begin
      if Result <> '' then
        Result := Result + ',';
      Result := Result + GetEnumName(TypeInfo, I);
    end;
  if Brackets then
    Result := '[' + Result + ']';
end;

procedure StringToSet(Info: PTypeInfo; var SetParam; const Value: AnsiString);
var
  P: PAnsiChar;
  EnumInfo: PTypeInfo;
  EnumName: AnsiString;
  EnumValue, SetValue: Longint;

  function NextWord(var P: PAnsiChar): AnsiString;
  var
    I: Integer;
  begin
    I := 0;
    // scan til whitespace
    while not (P[I] in [',', ' ', #0,']']) do
      Inc(I);
    SetString(Result, P, I);
    // skip whitespace
    while P[I] in [',', ' ',']'] do
      Inc(I);
    Inc(P, I);
  end;

begin
  SetOrdValue(Info, SetParam, 0);
  if Value = '' then
    Exit;

  SetValue := 0;
  P := PAnsiChar(Value);
  // skip leading bracket and whitespace
  while P^ in ['[',' '] do
    Inc(P);
  EnumInfo := GetTypeData(Info)^.CompType^;
  EnumName := NextWord(P);
  while EnumName <> '' do
  begin
    EnumValue := GetEnumValue(EnumInfo, EnumName);
    if EnumValue < 0 then
    begin
      SetOrdValue(Info, SetParam, 0);
      Exit;
    end;
    Include(TIntegerSet(SetValue), EnumValue);
    EnumName := NextWord(P);
  end;
  SetOrdValue(Info, SetParam, SetValue);
end;
```

Example usage:

```
var
  A: TAlignSet;
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  // set to string
  A := [alClient, alLeft, alTop];
  S := SetToString(TypeInfo(TAlignSet), A, True);
  ShowMessage(Format('%s ($%x)', [S, Byte(A)]));

  // string to set
  S := '[alNone, alRight, alCustom]';
  StringToSet(TypeInfo(TAlignSet), A, S);
  ShowMessage(Format('%s ($%x)', [SetToString(TypeInfo(TAlignSet), A, True), Byte(A)]));
end;
```

Comment: good approach to use untyped var parameter instead of that TypInfo unit offers (still looks like derivative work, tho)

Comment: `SetToString` crashes if using it on enums with defined numbers, for example `snOne = 1, snTwo = 2, snThree = 3` etc. It appears to have to do with the fact that they're no longer 0 index based.

Answer (score 1):

You have right function name already - [`StringToSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/TypInfo.StringToSet). However, usage is tricky:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
type PFontStyles = ^TFontStyles;       // typecast helper declaration
var Styles: Integer;                   // receives set bitmap after parsing
{$IF SizeOf(TFontStyles) > SizeOf(Integer)}
{$MESSAGE FATAL 'Panic. RTTI functions will work with register-sized sets only'}
{$IFEND}
begin
  Styles := StringToSet(               // don't forget to use TypInfo (3)
    PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(TFontStyles)),  // this kludge is required for overload (1)
    '[fsBold, fsUnderline]'
  );
  Font.Style := PFontStyles(@Styles)^; // hack to bypass strict typecast rules (2)
  Update();                            // let form select amended font into Canvas
  Canvas.TextOut(0, 0, 'ME BOLD! ME UNDERLINED!');
end;
```

(1) because initially borland limited this function family to PropInfo pointers and TypeInfo() intrinsic returns untyped pointer, hence the typecast

(2) typecasting requires types to be of same size, hence the referencing and dereferencing to different type (TFontStyles is a Byte)

---

Nitpicker special: (3) This snippet works out of the box in D2010+. Earlier versions has required dependency missing - namely `StringToSet(TypeInfo: PTypeInfo; ...` overload (see docwiki link above). This problem is solvable by copypasting (yeah, but TTypeInfo is lower-level than TPropInfo) original function and doing 2 (two) minor edits. By obvious reasons i'm not going to publish copyrighted code, but here is the relevant `diff`:

```
1c1,2
< function StringToSet(PropInfo: PPropInfo; const Value: string): Integer;
---
> {$IF RTLVersion < 21.0}
> function StringToSet(TypeInfo: PTypeInfo; const Value: string): Integer; overload;
37c38
<   EnumInfo := GetTypeData(PropInfo^.PropType^)^.CompType^;
---
>   EnumInfo := GetTypeData(TypeInfo)^.CompType^;
47a49
> {$IFEND}
```

Comment: -1. You should not have to rely on a 'hack' or a 'kludge'. It's not compatible across versions. @RRUZ's answer is better, even though it's restricted to published properties (which is not necessarily the case in XE).

Comment: @Ken White, you should read description more careful. I dismiss a charge for "kludge", typecast there is required. And of course it is compatible across, while TypInfo.StringToSet have PTypeInfo overload. In which RTL version it didnt work for you?

Comment: I have very little experience of this part of Delphi, but the code above does not compile for me in Delphi 2009. The compiler says "[DCC Error] Unit4.pas(32): E2010 Incompatible types: 'PPropInfo' and 'PTypeInfo'". If I replace the `PTypeInfo` cast with a `PPropInfo` cast, the code compiles, but I get an AV at runtime.

Comment: @user: The 'kludge' came from your own comment in the code. Aren't you aware of what you posted? 'Hack' also came from your own words, BTW, before you comment on that as well.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, it was a dangerous experiment :) Looks like `StringToSet(TypeInfo: PTypeInfo; ...` overload has been added only in D2010. Meanwhile i got it working in D7, D207 with nasty copypasta from TypInfo.pas

Comment: @Ken White, so, you noticed "kludge" instead of "unicord" and "hack" instead of "rainbow" and came to conclusion what this code is not working?

Comment: @user: No, I came to the conclusion that the code was a really bad solution, and used your own words to explain why. It's a poorly written, badly designed answer and should not be used in any type of production code anywhere. You explained why yourself, and should have known better than to post a 'kludgy' 'hack' answer (which you obviously were aware of, since you identified it as such yourself).

Comment: @Ken White, i'm not going sell anything with sweet words. Your picking on "kludge" comment instead of code itself obviously points out what you have little idea about what this code does. And more important - why so and not another way.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, you are welcome to try out if you are still interested in version-independent solution. I've included dependency patching recipe in the answer.

Comment: @user: Last try. I downvoted your answer because it was very bad code. The fact I used your own words to describe it doesn't change the fact your code was very bad - using your own words simply shows you were also aware it was bad to start with. Being snarky with me doesn't change the fact the code was terrible from the start.

Comment: @Ken White, i'm pretty sure you have own reasons to downvote, as you never provided any technical critics. Nor reported any practical issues (Look at Andreas's comment).

Comment: @Downvoter step into the light - OMG could't you choose some shorter sensible nick ? Anyway I would say the 3 downvotes are because you've posted a very specific answer (if you compare it with RRUZ's one) and you were quite offensive to some people here and from my point of view I don't get the `SizeOf(TFontStyles) > SizeOf(Integer)` condition or do you thing there will be so many font styles in the future ? And I haven't checked your previous posts, maybe this would cause another -1. For those reasons I'm voting for RRUZ and TOndrej.

Comment: @daemon_x, in the fact my answer is more **general** than RRUZ's one. `SizeOf` assertion makes that "hackish" typecast never result in junk data from the outside of variable boundaries (for more details - see related comments in TypInfo.pas). TOndrej's answer is a very similar to the mine, except he used different solution while converting register-sized RTTI return value to the target set type (and i still have legal concerns). Hope i explained all **technical issues** to you.

Comment: @Downvoter... - If we stay at `SizeOf` condition, in D2009 (or at least there) is a comment (and part of a code) where the limit is set to `SizeOf(Integer) * 8` but even if it would be `integer` I don't think that someone will work with set of `2,147,483,647` of combinations.

Comment: @daemon_x, two reasons: a) i was accused for being "incompatible across the versions" and more important b) machine assures for you what losing strong typing in that pointer cast will remain completely safe. (BTW you miscalculated that, at maximum 32 set members will fit in 32-bit register, extending base enum to 33 values will cause error to be reported at compile time preventing any undefined behaviour at run time)