# Convert the numbers of a set to String

Tags: delphi

I would like to save the numbers from `MySet = set of 1..8` to `MyString : String`. Is there a function like `IntToStr` which can do this?

I have a scheduler, which takes in a string in the form of `(* * * * * * * *)` . One of the stars represents the days of execution, and `MySet` is the list of days. For example 1 is monday, 2 is tuesday. I have to save the numbers from the set to that string, so it would look something like this: `(0 0 15 * * * 1,2,3 *)` . This means, that the scheduler will trigger every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday at 15:00.

**If you want to read more about this format:** http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Comment: I highly doubt it - you'll most likely have to write one yourself for a custom type. What kind of output string do you expect? Delimited by spaces? Commas? Dashes?

Comment: see: http://tondrej.blogspot.it/2007/10/settostring-stringtoset.html

Comment: Have you tied using Ord() to convert an individual element to an integer, then stringing the results together?

Comment: @fantaghirocco I'm wondering if that works on a set of integers - seems to be for a set of enums. Honestly, I never imagined using `set` for anything other than enums.

Comment: Even if this is about string2set, there's also the the case of your interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351355/in-delphi-can-a-string-be-converted-to-a-set

Comment: @JerryDodge just to give the OP a starting point

Comment: Well I mean defining a set type as OP's question does.

Comment: Then why not define... `type TWeekday = (wdMonday, wdTuesday, wdWednesday, wdThursday, wdFriday, wdSaturday, wdSunday); TWeekdays = set of TWeekday;` It is much clearer to understand and work with. This article covers a very similar scenario: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Sets

Comment: @JerryDodge you missed the 8th day of the OP's week :D

Comment: @fantaghirocco I was just scratching my head over that actually. Friday night? Also over how some are delimited with spaces, and others with commas. Which brings me back to my first comment.

Comment: The 8th number stands for: every day including holidays. :)

@JerryDodge CRON format. http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Comment: That sounds like a nasty approach. What if a user wants every Wednesday except holidays? Or Christmas but not New Years? That kind of info should be kept separate. But your comment changes it quite a bit. I think what you actually want is an array of int, not a set.

Comment: Okay, you should have mentioned all this information in your question. Please [edit] it and do so. In that case, you don't want either a `set` or an `array`. This is what you call an X/Y question - you have X problem, but ask how to solve Y.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [for..in](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements) iterator to produce the wanted string:

```
Type
  MySet = set of 1..8;

function MySetToString(const s: MySet): String;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for i in s do begin
    Result := Result + IntToStr(i) + ',';
  end;
  SetLength(Result,Length(Result)-1);
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this works for OP's original question, but the comments exposed they really want to format a CRON expression, in which a `set` isn't even suitable for.

Comment: @JerryDodge, that is supplemental information, not needed to answer the question.

Comment: Exactly, just pointing out. In the end, OP won't even need this, because the result is not a valid CRON expression matching the format OP is asking for.

Comment: @JerryDodge, there are several cron versions.

Comment: I'm just going by the string value OP wants it to produce as stated in the question `(0 0 15 * * * 1,2,3 *)`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!
@JerryDodge I am iterating through the elements of the set, and saving the numbers into a temporary string, then, I can use that string with the CRON format.

Comment: @ReyesJ. The real problem goes deeper though. You shouldn't format a string, then de-format it just to re-format it again (as I understand your intentions). Just serialize the expression how it needs to be in the first place. I'm not saying this answer's wrong, in fact I said it's right. It's just not what you need.

Comment: One of the disappointing aspects of the documentation is that there is no statement of the enumeration order of a set. I think we all know that items are enumerated in order of ascending ordinal value. But it sucks that the documentation makes no such statement.