# The "set of" operator in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I was reading that the `set of` operator in `Pascal` represents the Mathematical "[Power Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)", but I can't seem to understand how.

For example, on [Wikibooks, The Free Textbook Project, Page “Pascal Programming/Sets”](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Special:PermaLink/3512615#general) I have found the following piece of code:

```
program setDemo(output);
type
    skill = (cooking, cleaning, driving, videogames, eating);
var
    slob: set of skill;
begin
    slob := [videogames, eating];
end.
```

What do we get from `slob := [videogames, eating]` command? I guess that `slob` will contain those two "skills", but how does it represented by the Power set?

Comment: `set of` is not an operator. It is more like a 'keyword' used for defining types.

Comment: If you are familiar with binary arithmetic, a Pascal `set` is a bit array where the subtype enumerates the bit position.  Typically a `set` can't have more than 32, 64, or 256 items (depending on the implementation) due to the efficiency of manipulating more than 4, 8, or 32 bytes containing the bits.

Comment: `set of` is a datatype, not an operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, being a subset of the set of (all) skills, `slob` is an element of the power set of the set of (all) skills.

---

In Pascal, `set of A`, where `A` is some ordinal type, is a type that represents a mathematical set of elements of type `A`. More precisely, each value of this type is such a mathematical set. For example, in Delphi (a modern version of Pascal), you have the

`TFontStyle = (fsBold, fsItalic, fsUnderline, fsStrikeOut)`

enumeration and the corresponding `TFontStyles = set of TFontStyle` set type. While a value of type `TFontStyle` is simply either of `fsBold`, `fsItalic`, `fsUnderline`, or `fsStrikeOut`, a value of type `TFontStyles` is a set of font styles (or attributes), such as `[fsBold, fsUnderline]`. If you set a label's `Font.Style` property to this value, the label's font will be bold and underlined.

You seems to understand this, so let me instead focus on the 'power set' concept, which you seem to be confused about.

Using mathematical syntax, consider the set

```
A = {cooking, cleaning, driving, gaming, eating}
```

of skills. The power set of A, sometimes denoted P(A) or 2^A, is the set of all subsets of A. (Hence, it is a set whose members are sets.) Some of the members of this set are listed below:

```
{} (=the empty set)
{cooking}
{driving}
{cooking, cleaning}
{cleaning, gaming, eating}
{cooking, cleaning, driving, eating}
{cooking, cleaning, driving, gaming, eating} (=A)
```

In total, P(A) consists of 2^|A| = 2^5 = 32 elements. Indeed, in a given subset of A, either `cooking` is part of it or it is not (2 options), and for each of these options, either `cleaning` is part of the subset or it is not (2 options), and so on. The total number of combinations thus becomes 2×2×...×2 = 32.

Now, given the Pascal enumeration

```
skill = (cooking, cleaning, driving, gaming, eating)
```

`set of skill` is a type whose values are sets of `skill` values, like `[cooking, cleaning]` or `[cleaning, gaming, eating]` (using Pascal syntax). Clearly, each such value -- a *subset* of A -- is an *element* of P(A), in much the same way as each value of type `skill` is an element of A itself.

---

You asked specifically,

> What do we get from `slob := [videogames, eating]` command?

You assign the value `[videogames, eating]` to the variable `slob`. This is a value of type `set of skill`, and this particular value contains the members `videogames` and `eating`.

Under the hood, a set value in Delphi is represented using a number of bytes (each set type has a specific size), and each possible element in the set is represented by a specific bit. In Delphi, the type `set of A` is only allowed if `A` has no more than 256 values. If `A` has this many values (say if `A` is `byte`), this requires `set of A` to have 256 bits (so that there are 2^256 = 1.16 × 10^77 possible values of type `set of A`).

Sometimes people wonder why they cannot declare a type `set of integer`. But an integer is a 32-bit value, so there are 2^32 = 4294967296 such values. A value of the hypothetical type `set of integer` would thus require 4294967296 bytes, or 4 GB. That's a huge amount of memory for a single variable!

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Is `[videogames, eating]` an array? how to print it? (tried with `WriteLn`).

Comment: No, [arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Arrays) and [sets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) are not the same thing, even though they share the `[]` syntax. There is no one-liner to print a set (in a pretty way), but not many lines are required. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861338/282848.

Comment: @vesii: No, `[videogames, eating]` is not an array. It's a set.

Comment: If I understand your answer correct, *"a pascal set represents the power set"* is not an incorrect statement because a pascal set is a subset of the power set. Do I understand correct?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: No, a Pascal set is not a subset of the power set P(A). A Pascal set is an element of the power set P(A). This is the same thing as a subset of the underlying set A.