# how to read/write set enumeration from text file with delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to use SQL like condition in Delphi as

```
    if VarI in SOMESET then 
    ...
```

[SOMESET]  to read from any text file.

Store few numbers in any text file like ini/txt and read it from file and replace it with set so that we can use in operator with if condition.

Comment: SQL's and Delphi's `in` operators are quite different. Anyway, did you see `Typinfo.SetToString` and `StringToSet` functions?

Comment: Also, related and possible dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351355/in-delphi-can-a-string-be-converted-to-a-set

Comment: You can use sets for numbers, but you're limited to 0..256, as you're only allowed byte type. If you know your possible values at compile time you can define an enumerated type and use @FreeConsulting link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, the simple answer is yes. Your terminology may be a bit off - set means something quite specific in Delphi, but I don't think that is what you mean. Also, I don't think you are asking about the specifics of loading and saving so I have not included that. Instead I think you are asking how to allow 'in' to be defined in this specific case, and here is how

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TMySet = record
  private
    function GetEntry(const i: integer): integer;
  public
    Entries : array of integer;
    // procedure LoadFromFile( const pFromFile : TFileName );
    class operator in ( const pTest : integer; pMyset : TMyset ) : boolean;
    property Entry[ const i : integer ] : integer
             read GetEntry; default;
  end;

implementation

{ TMySet }

function TMySet.GetEntry(const i: integer): integer;
begin
  Result := Entries[ i ]; // allow default exceptions to occur
end;

class operator TMySet.in(const pTest: integer; pMyset: TMyset): boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(pMyset.Entries) to High(pMyset.Entries) do
  begin
    if i = pMyset[ i ] then
    begin
      Result := TRUE;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  // else
  Result := FALSE;
end;

end.
```

I hope I have understood your question, and that this helps.